# gmlib issue - search direction not working

Tags: gmlib

can you please help me with this issue? See description below.

@author Xavier Martinez (cadetill)
@version 1.5.4

Projekt MegaDemo

After clicking on button Search Direction nothing is happening.

Program cycles in unit GMDirection in procedure Execute:

ExecuteScript('GetDirections', Params);
  repeat
    TGMGenFunc.ProcessMessages;
  until (GetIntegerField(DirectionsForm, DirectionsFormResponse) = 1);
  GetRetournedData;!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I temporary solved this problem in GMMap.pas unit

```
function TGMObjects.ExecuteScript(NameFunct, Params: string): Boolean;
begin
    Result := False;

    Map.FDocLoaded := true; <<- new line

    if (csDesigning in ComponentState) or not Assigned(FMap) or
        not Map.Active or not Map.FDocLoaded then Exit;

    Result := FMap.ExecuteScript(NameFunct, Params);
end;
```