# Can't set Marker with GmLib 1.5.3 or 1.5.4

Tags: gmlib

I have a problem to set the Marker since Today.

Know I have download the newest version 1.5.4.
But it doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023810/gmlib-issue-search-direction-not-working) for a temporary fix, that may help.

You may still have some other issues.

You can now download ver [1.5.5](https://github.com/cadetill/gmlib_v1) for a complete fix.

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate, please mark it as such instead of posting a link to the original question as an answer.

Comment: It is not a duplicate question, however the same response would fix this problem as well.